# Where is the order of names in gdm login screen stored?

Tags: login-screen, gdm, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the order of the users in the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4324/how-can-i-change-the-order-of-the-users-in-the-login-screen)

Where is the users' login history stored that governs the order in which the users' names appear in the login window? Background: I want to manipulate the order of the names.

--

[[This is the most counter-intuitive forum site I have dealt with yet.]]

Comment: Not duplicate. The title is similar, but the question itself is intentionally specific. After I got my fingers slapped for asking my question over there, honestly, don't give me this.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to configure the order of names: Names are ordered by their login frequency as returned by ConsoleKit (see the output of`ck-history --frequent`). The numbers are extracted from the log files in `/var/log/ConsoleKit/` directly, so there is no simple way to change them. You could still repeatedly login as one user, though, that would move the user to the top ;)

Comment: Thank you. I will try deleting /var/log/ConsoleKit/* (or maybe just the most recent logs) after a bout of maintenance logins so that the real users end up back on top fast.

Answer (score 0):

The order in my login screen seems to be random; I only have my user and a guest user - I never use the guest account but sometimes it appears as first on the list