# Automatically execute script that requires password when I login with my second user

Tags: command-line, 18.04, users

So I am changing all of the question so  you can understand my purpose:

I have this `script.sh`:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh
cd /home/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin/ 
hiveserver2 & 
sudo /opt/hue/build/env/bin/hue runserver &
```

I want it to be run automatically when ubuntu boots and I login to second user **hadoop**.

**PROBLEM:**

This script should be executed by user **hadoop**. This **hadoop** user has a password. Ubuntu boots on another user by default.

How should I do please? **Newbie alert!**

Comment: but you don't want hadoop to become a user with sudo priveleges?

Comment: He already is. Actually my main purpose is to get Hadoop to execute a script when I start my lap. But to give him control I need to do su - hadoop (because lap starts with another user by default) which requires a manually given password. So the idea is to replace the default user by hadoop

Comment: oh but you'll always have to type the password though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the order of the users in the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4324/how-can-i-change-the-order-of-the-users-in-the-login-screen)

Comment: @Fabby, almost. Only I am trying to launch the script from a secondary user not the default oe

Comment: @AbderrahmenM **Close vote retracted**  Please [edit] your question if the herd would still close it and make it clear ***in the title*** that you need another user then the default one.  **;-) 0:-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `man sudoers` and you can do `sudo -u hadoop` the script, and allow user `hadoop` to execute those specific commands `NOPASSWWD`.